# multiple selection on custom picker C# UWP

Tags: c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml, picker, xamarin.uwp

I've been looking on forums and internet about a custom picker on C#, I have a picker already functional, but some of my research throw me that you are only able to select 1 item of the custom Picker, this is the code im using to deploy the picker.

**Picker**

```
<custom:CustomPicker x:Name="pickerCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding listCategoriesName}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCategory}" SelectedIndexChanged="pickerCategories_SelectedIndexChanged" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="White"/>
```

the item source are given to the picker as a list of object from a database
is there a way to be able to select multiple index of the custom picker? 
for Example...

```
Picker pk = new Picker(); pk.SelectionMode=Multiple;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you requirement, you could make a custom `Picker` renderer in the native uwp project. And then make a new `DataTemplate` for displaying `ComboBox` item that contain checkbox in the native control.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateEmployee" >
    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Content,Mode=TwoWay}" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

For `CustomPickerRenderer`, you should pass the Forms `Picker` item source to native control(ComboBox). And when combobox drop down closed, you could execute `InvokeAction` method to send `Data` to the Forms `Picker`.

```
public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.ItemsSource = e.NewElement.ItemsSource;
        Control.ItemTemplate = (Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate)App.Current.Resources["templateEmployee"];
        Control.DropDownClosed += Control_DropDownClosed;

    }

    private void Control_DropDownClosed(object sender, object e)
    {
        var NewElement = Element as CustomPicker;
        var items = (sender as ComboBox).ItemsSource;
        NewElement.InvokeAction(items);
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyPicker.ItemsSource = new MainViewModel().itemSource;
    MyPicker.RegisterAction(IsCheckItems);
}
private List<Item> SelecItms = new List<Item>();
private void IsCheckItems(object data)
{
    var items = data as ObservableCollection<Item>;
    var str = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.IsCheck)
        {
            SelecItms.Add(item);
            str.AppendLine(item.Content);
        }
    }
    SeleitemLabel.Text = str.ToString();
}
```

[image]

And I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/MuiltSelectPicker.git). Please check.

Comment: it was really usefull, i was able to solved my problem !!

Comment: If you use UWP PickerRenderer ... and you change the layout the CustomPicker is in,  .... then your UWP application crashes.  Wasted FIVE weeks before this UWP twaddle pulled the rug from under my feet.  Be warned.