# Multiple select for custom picker XAML not working

Tags: c#, xaml, mobile, xamarin.forms, uwp

Going here and using this: [multiple selection on custom picker C# UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165019/multiple-selection-on-custom-picker-c-sharp-uwp) And I have uploaded the code sample.

I was able to download code sample and got it to work but when I tried it in my project I get a ***stackPanel*** type was not found.

I notice the xmlns paths are different but I need the one that I have.

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"
         x:Class="SDMSApp.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HasBackButton" Value="false"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateEmployee">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <controls:CheckBox Content="{Binding Content,Mode=TwoWay}" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: StackPanel is specific to UWP.  XF has a StackLayout which is similar

Comment: Put the StackPanel XAML in the UWP project, not in the 'common' project or the Android project (or the IOS project).  When you build the UWP project, it should compile with no problem

Comment: Thank you Richard Hammond.  It worked like a charm once I moved it to UWP project.